# Can not delete the old linux-image-

Tags: dpkg

Can not delete the old linux-image-....
Tried

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
```

But I'm having error

```
(Reading database ... 278185 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 13: /etc/default/grub: acpi: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Can you append the output of `uname -r` to your question, please?

Comment: Also post the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`. From the error message it seems there is something wrong there.

Comment: @CharlesGreen : uname -r result is 3.13.0-35-generic

Comment: @Salem: 
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
acpi = nolapic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in this line of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" acpi = nolapic
```

It should be

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=nolapic"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Salem.
Edited the grub and all started to work